# addAttributeToSelect in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, collection

`addAttributeToSelect` is not working in magento 2. i tried below but it is loading all item.

```
$groupCollection = $this->_productloader->create();
$groupCollection->addAttributeToFilter('sku','24-MB02');
$groupCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name,sku');
```

below is result

```
{"entity_id":"6","attribute_set_id":"15","type_id":"simple","sku":"24-MB02","has_options":"0","required_options"
:"0","created_at":"2016-04-26 06:40:51","updated_at":"2016-04-26 06:40:51","is_salable":"1"}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use an array:

```
addAttributeToSelect(['name','sku'])
```

Alternative:

```
addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get all the attribute simple add below code it will load all the attributes.

```
$groupCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array('*'));
```